# How to use group_by (or similar command) in lists R

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I had to deal with meteorological datasets with more then a hundred stations. Data structure looks like this (month goes from 1 to 12 and year from 1965 to 2020):

| station | month | year | hourlymax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CYBG | 1 | 1965 | 8 |
| CYBC | 1 | 1965 | 6 |
| CYKG | 1 | 1965 | 3.5 |
| CYBG | 1 | 1965 | 2 |
| CYBC | 1 | 1965 | 3.5 |
| CYKG | 1 | 1665 | 4 |

I used the function split `Stations <- split(all_stations, all_stations$station`, to split this big dataset by station. I am now wondering if it is possible to apply certain function to all of the datasets in the list. For example, I want to get the monthly mean of a variable. I tried the code (list name is station)

```
for (i in 1:length(Stations)) {
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(result = mean(hourlymax) )
}
```

There might be better ways of spliting the data at first, I don't know any...

Any help/comment is REALLY appreciated! I'm quite new and learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all ready split the original dataframe into a list of data frames, this is suited for using `lapply` or `sapply` functions depending on whether you want the results as a list or a vector.

```
result_vector <- sapply(Stations, function(x) { 
     mean(x$hourlymax)
})
```

Or if you want to use the dplyr strategy, then use `group_by` on the original dataframe

```
result_df <- all_stations %>% group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(result = mean(hourlymax))
```

Comment: Thank you, I finally gave up on the idea of splitting the data and used something similar as your second alternative, worked well!

Comment: @Will_8011 Instead of using `split()` and then `sapply()` to take the `mean` you could instead use `tapply(all_stations$hourlymax, all_stations$station, mean)`